# Pandas idiomatic way to do a dictionary lookup

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, series

I have a pandas series of integers (they are restricted to some smallish finite subset) and a dictionary of those possible integers to doubles. I'd like to create a new series that looks like `dictionary[series]`. What's the pandas idiomatic way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) to do this.

For example, here's a dictionary mapping a few integers `n` to `n + 0.5`, and a Series of integers:

```
>>> d = {1: 1.5, 2: 2.5, 3: 3.5, 4: 4.5, 5: 5.5}
>>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> s
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
dtype: int64
```

To create the new Series, you can write:

```
>>> s.map(d)
0    1.5
1    2.5
2    3.5
3    4.5
4    5.5
dtype: float64
```

As well as a dictionary, `map` can also accept another Series as an argument, or a function.